# Practice program function

Tags: python

This is the 2nd practice part of the book "Automate the boring stuff with python" in chapter 5 on page 120. The task is to program the `addToInventory` function. The rest is pretty much given. Python tells me:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

at this line `inventory(addedItems[k]) = inventory(addedItems[k]) + 1`. I tried for hours, but I don't know where my mistake is. It seems logical to me that this line increases the stuff/inventory by 1 depending on what the current item in the `dragonLoot` is.

```
def displayInventory(Inventory): #rpints out the whole inventory
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in Inventory.items():
        item_total = item_total + stuff.get(k,v)
        print(k, v)
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems): #merges the dragonloot box into our stuff/inventory
    for k in range(len(addedItems)):
        inventory.setdefault(addedItems[k], 0) #creates empy keynames in the stuff/inventory dictionary
        inventory(addedItems[k]) = inventory(addedItems[k]) + 1
    return (inventory)

stuff = {"gold": 42, "rope": 1}
dragonLoot = ["gold", "dagger", "gold", "gold", "ruby"]
stuff = addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(stuff)
```

Comment: Typo. You should index dictionaries with square brackets, not parentheses: `inventory[addedItems[k]] = inventory[addedItems[k]] + 1`. Or, more concisely, `inventory[addedItems[k]] += 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to to use a dictionary, for which you'd need to use `[` and `]`, not `(` and `)`. Switch those out in your line `inventory(addedItems[k]) = inventory(addedItems[k]) + 1`

```
def displayInventory(Inventory): #rpints out the whole inventory
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in Inventory.items():
        item_total = item_total + stuff.get(k,v)
        print(k, v)
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems): #merges the dragonloot box into our stuff/inventory
    for k in range(len(addedItems)):
        inventory.setdefault(addedItems[k], 0) #creates empy keynames in the stuff/inventory dictionary
        inventory[addedItems[k]] = inventory[addedItems[k]] + 1
    return (inventory)

stuff = {"gold": 42, "rope": 1}
dragonLoot = ["gold", "dagger", "gold", "gold", "ruby"]
stuff = addToInventory(stuff, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo, as the comment suggests. `()` (in this context) calls a function, and since Python doesn't do type-checking, `inventory(addedItems[k])` part of `inventory(addedItems[k]) = inventory(addedItems[k]) + 1` is considered a function call even though you later on you send a dictionary as the parameter. Since you cannot assign to a function call, this is a SytaxError, and the code isn't able to compile. What you meant to do was using `[]` to get elements from a dictionary:

```
inventory[addedItems[k]] = inventory(addedItems[k]) + 1
```